# Go Templates - Loading from an object store / Database

Tags: templates, go, mux, gorilla

I'm rebuilding an app that supports customer specific templating (themes) from node.js to Go.

I'm currently using [render](https://github.com/unrolled/render) to render my template files but what I actually need to do access templates that are stored in an object store such as Cloudfiles.

In node.js I've done this with express and I'm overriding the `render()` method but I've not been able to figure out how to do this in Go.

I essentially need to do something like this:

```
func (c *Controller) MyRouteHandler (rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // retrieve the store from the context (assigned in middleware chain)
    store := context.Get(req, "store").(*Store) 

    ... do some stuff like load the entity from the database

    // retrieve the template from the Object store and 
    // create the template instance (template.New("template").Parse(...))
    tpl := c.ObjectStore.LoadTemplate(store, entity.TemplateFile)

    // I know render's .HTML function takes the path to the template 
    // so I'll probably need to show the html a different way
    c.HTML(rw, http.StatusOK, tpl, &PageContext{Title: "My Page", Entity: &entity})
}
```

I can dynamically include sub-templates by doing something like this if needed: http://play.golang.org/p/7BCPHdKRi2 but it doesn't seem like a great way if I'm honest.

I've searched for a solution to this but keep hitting road blocks. Any advice / assistance would be great.

**Edit:**

In essence, I'm asking the following:

1. How can I load a specific template from a datastore on a per-request basis.
2. How can I then send that as a response to the client

Comment: so your real problem is to find a way loading text from Cloudfiles?

Comment: No, I can load the content of the file from Cloudfiles. That bit is easy. It's being able to render it as a template using Go

Comment: sorry i not know your really question still.

Comment: From what I can tell, by default, Go's templating requires the templates to available at compile-time and you need to re-compile for template changes to take affect. I need to load the templates from a external source (like a database) and parse them on the fly before each request.

Comment: of cause you can load Go's template content at runtime, just to read template content "on the fly" and invoke Parse() function.

Comment: @JiangYD Ok, That's what I'm asking. I've edited my question.

Comment: Note that remotely fetching, parsing and then executing a template during a request/response cycle is hugely inefficient (and very slow). Can you not fetch them at program start, parse them and then make them available in a global or env struct you pass around?

Comment: @elithrar Unfortunately not as each customer can modify their templates

Comment: You probably want to do some caching as well (saving the template), otherwise it'd be quite slow.

Comment: (be careful with user modified templates: huge security risk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can I load a specific template from a datastore on a per-request basis.

```
//take HTTP for example:
resp, err := http.Get("http://mytemplates.com/template1")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
templateString := string(body)
```

How can I then send that as a response to the client

```
tmpl, err := template.New("name").Parse(templateString)
tmpl.Execute(rw, &yourDataModel{})
```